# Center a text box inside a div width:100% leaving some margin in all sides

Tags: html, css, textbox, width, centering

I need to put a text box inside a div that has 100% width leaving `margin` in all sides.
My problem is that I wasn't able to put right margin, cause the 100% width of the text box (that is necessary!).
So the `textbox` and the div container must have 100% width (cause responsive) and the `textbox` needs 8px margin in all sides.

```css
.search-cont {
    background-color: #c8c7cc;
    width:100%;
    height:44px;
    overflow:hidden;
    transition: all 0.5s;
    z-index:997;
    position:fixed;
}

.search-text {
    border-radius:5px;
    border:0px;
    height:28px;
    padding:0px;
    padding-left:6px;
    width: 100% !important;
    margin: 8px !important;
    box-sizing:border-box;
    display:block;
    background-color:#fff;
}

::-webkit-input-placeholder {
   text-align: center;
}

:-moz-placeholder { /* Firefox 18- */
   text-align: center;  
}

::-moz-placeholder {  /* Firefox 19+ */
   text-align: center;  
}

:-ms-input-placeholder {  
   text-align: center; 
}
```

```html
<div id="search-cont" class="search-cont">
  <div><input type="text" id="search-text" class="search-text" placeholder="Search" /></div>
</div>
```

There is the example --> [DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/5b0gqLk3/)

Comment: Who are you writing?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `padding` on the parent tag instead of `margin` on the element.

You need to add `box-sizing:border-box;` to the parent (the best practice is to add this to any element using `*` selector).

```css
* {
  box-sizing:border-box;  
}

body {
  margin:0;  
}

.search-cont {
  background-color: #c8c7cc;
  width:100%;
  height:44px;
  overflow:hidden;
  transition: all 0.5s;
  z-index:997;
  position:fixed;
  padding:8px;
}

.search-text {
    border-radius:5px;
    border:0px;
    height:28px;
    padding:0px;
    padding-left:6px;
    width: 100% !important;
    /*margin: 8px !important;*/
    box-sizing:border-box;
    display:block;
    background-color:#fff;
}

::-webkit-input-placeholder {
   text-align: center;
}

:-moz-placeholder { /* Firefox 18- */
   text-align: center;  
}

::-moz-placeholder {  /* Firefox 19+ */
   text-align: center;  
}

:-ms-input-placeholder {  
   text-align: center; 
}
```

```html
<div id="search-cont" class="search-cont">
  <div><input type="text" id="search-text" class="search-text" placeholder="Search" /></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Use this small fix:

1. `* {box-sizing: border-box;}`
2. Remove `width` and `margin` on the same elements.
3. Use `padding` on `div` instead of `margin` on the `input`.

**Working Snippet**

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.search-cont {
  background-color: #c8c7cc;
  height: 44px;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: all 0.5s;
  z-index: 997;
  position: fixed;
  left: 10px;
  right: 10px;
}

.search-cont div {
  padding: 8px;
}
.search-text {
  border-radius: 5px;
  border: 0px;
  height: 28px;
  padding: 0px;
  text-indent: 6px;
  width: 100% !important;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: block;
  background-color: #fff;
}
::-webkit-input-placeholder {
  text-align: center;
}
:-moz-placeholder {
  /* Firefox 18- */
  text-align: center;
}
::-moz-placeholder {
  /* Firefox 19+ */
  text-align: center;
}
:-ms-input-placeholder {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div id="search-cont" class="search-cont">
  <div>
    <input type="text" id="search-text" class="search-text" placeholder="Search" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`box-sizing`](https://developer.mozilla.org/nl/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing) to achieve the desired result (also - the `body` tag has default `margin: 8px`)

[Fiddle using box-sizing](https://jsfiddle.net/5b0gqLk3/6/)

```
/*resetting body margin*/
body {
    margin: 0;
}

.search-cont {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    padding: 8px;
    /*...snipped...*/
}

.search-text {
    margin: 8px; /*REMOVE THIS LINE*/
    /*...snipped...*/
}
```

Using box sizing however is like using a different box model (which it is).

As an alternative you can use [`calc`](https://developer.mozilla.org/nl/docs/Web/CSS/calc) to achieve the same effect except you have control over the calculations.

[Fiddle using calc](https://jsfiddle.net/5b0gqLk3/8/)

```
.search-text {
    width: calc(100% - 16px); /*margin on both sides*/
    /*...snipped...*/
}
```

Also on another note, you didn't need any `!important` there, `!important` exists to overwrite overly specific selectors - using it isn't necessarily bad but using it too easily kinda defeats it's purpose of being a *last resort* :).

Answer (score 0):

just add a padding to the div. and box-sizing:border-box;

```
padding: 8px;
-moz-box-sizing: border-box;
-webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
box-sizing: border-box;
```

Than remove the margin on the input.

Answer (score 0):

if you still want to use `width:100%` in `.search-text` you can do a little hack with either `padding` and/or `border` like the following:

```
.search-text {
    border-radius:5px;
    border:0px;
    height:28px;
    padding:0px;
    padding-left:6px;
    width: 100% !important;
    border: 8px solid transparent !important; /* use border as margin */
    box-sizing:border-box;
    display:block;
    background-color:#fff;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

for .search-text you can use

```
width: calc(100% - 22px) !important;
```

where 22px = 8px(margin-left) + 8px(margin-right) + 6px(padding-left)